# How to deal with Beautifulsoup Recursion Error (or parse error)

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have a bunch of HTML files that I am trying to read it with Beautifulsoup. Some of them, I received an error. I tried decoding, encoding... but cannot find the problem. Thank you very much in advance.

Here is an example.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
new_text = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1723069/000121390018016357/0001213900-18-016357.txt')
soup = BeautifulSoup(new_text.content.decode('utf-8','ignore').encode("utf-8"),'lxml')
print(soup)
```

On Jupyter notebook, I get dead kernel error.
On Pycharm, I get the following error: (it repeats itself, so deleted some of them. But was quite long.)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/oe/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_5.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(soup)
  File "C:\Users\oe\Anaconda3\envs\TextAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1099, in __unicode__
    return self.decode()
  File "C:\Users\oe\Anaconda3\envs\TextAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 566, in decode
    indent_level, eventual_encoding, formatter)
  File "C:\Users\oe\Anaconda3\envs\TextAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1188, in decode
    indent_contents, eventual_encoding, formatter)
  File "C:\Users\oe\Anaconda3\envs\TextAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1257, in decode_contents
    formatter))
  File "C:\Users\oe\Anaconda3\envs\TextAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1188, in decode
    indent_contents, eventual_encoding, formatter)
  File "C:\Users\oe\Anaconda3\envs\TextAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1257, in decode_contents
    formatter))
  File "C:\Users\oe\Anaconda3\envs\TextAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1188, in decode
    indent_contents, eventual_encoding, formatter)
  File "C:\Users\oe\Anaconda3\envs\TextAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1257, in decode_contents
    formatter))
  File "C:\Users\oe\Anaconda3\envs\TextAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1188, in decode
    indent_contents, eventual_encoding, formatter)
  File "C:\Users\oe\Anaconda3\envs\TextAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1254, in decode_contents
    text = c.output_ready(formatter)
  File "C:\Users\oe\Anaconda3\envs\TextAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 745, in output_ready
    output = self.format_string(self, formatter)
  File "C:\Users\oe\Anaconda3\envs\TextAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 220, in format_string
    if isinstance(formatter, Callable):
  File "C:\Users\oe\Anaconda3\envs\TextAnalysis\lib\abc.py", line 190, in __instancecheck__
    subclass in cls._abc_negative_cache):
  File "C:\Users\oe\Anaconda3\envs\TextAnalysis\lib\_weakrefset.py", line 75, in __contains__
    return wr in self.data
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out those. Anything that can be done so that beautifulsoup skips them, or takes those as text? I just need the text without tags. So my main goal is to get rid of them. But dont mind if some of them stays.

Comment: this is actually just happening on the `print`. if you omit `print(soup)` you should be all set

Comment: If I call it somehwere else, it also stops. If I want to search it "new_text = re.search(r'.*?' + r'F-2', str(soup), re.DOTALL).group()" , again it goes in to loop. Do you think prettify() before or after beautifulsoup helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, I'm not sure what the underlying problem with your code is (although I don't get a dead kernel in a Jupyter notebook), but this seems to work:

```
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1723069/000121390018016357/0001213900-18-016357.txt'

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
new_text = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(new_text.text,'lxml')
print(soup.text)
```

Note that in `soup`, `new_text.content` is replaced with `new_text.text`, I had to drop the encode/decode parameters, and the `print` command had to be changed from `print(soup)` (which raised an error) to `print(soup.text)` which works fine. Maybe someone smarter can explain...

Another option that works is with:

```
import urllib.request

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
new_text2 = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(new_text2,'lxml')
print(soup.text)
```